# Setup phpmyadmin on Homestead box

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, homestead

Yes, I read the whole topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788096/how-to-setup-phpmyadmin-on-a-laravel-homestead-box). I tried all the methods that are described there. But I can not run this phpmyadmin thing on VM! 
And now it is more detailed. I installed Virtual Box, Vagrant and added Homestead. Then I set up Homestead:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: F:\Server\Homestead\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - F:\Server\Homestead\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: F:\Server
      to: /home/vagrant/server

sites:
    - map: corporate.com
      to: /home/vagrant/server/corporate/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

"corporate.com" - it's testing site. After starting VM it works fine.

And now let's go on the list of proposed solutions from the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788096/how-to-setup-phpmyadmin-on-a-laravel-homestead-box) about installing phpmyadmin for homestead

1)[image]
All of the above actions result in error 502 when attempting to access phpmyadmin

2)[image]
  [image]

These steps also resulted in a 502 error

3)
[image]

And this led to this result
[image]

4) Next
[image]
And result:
[image]

But why? `corporate` and `phpmyadmin` are in the same directory. However, the first one starts and works, and the phpmyadmin leads to this error.
I do not understand what's going on. I tried a lot of options, but not one of them does not work on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `.test` (or something else) instead of `.app`.

Chrome had an update recently which stops `.app` and `.dev` to work properly.