# How to set phpmyadmin route in homestead yaml file?

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, vagrant, yaml, homestead

I'm running a laravel project through homestead using vagrant. The project itself is working however, I'm struggling to get phpMyAdmin to work in homestead. I've downloaded and unziped phpmyadmin in homestead and I might be getting the path wrong in my yaml file.

[project_setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN643.jpg)

I've tried using the script

```
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grrnikos/pma/master/pma.sh | sh
```

and it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up phpMyAdmin on a Laravel Homestead box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788096/how-do-i-set-up-phpmyadmin-on-a-laravel-homestead-box)

Comment: Tried through this method before and I received this error C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 16 column 13 (Psych::SyntaxError) with option 2. Option 1 itself doesn't work at all and I believe it is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, you say it doesn't work. Why? Is there any messages? Is there any errors?

Comment: the first option left me with this error on phpmyadmin "Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS."

Comment: try some solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811804/phpmyadmin-failed-to-set-session-cookie-maybe-you-are-using-http-instead-of-htt)